# Mapping reduction properties exercise

Tags: automata, reductions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble understanding how to conclude if the statements are true or false, I would really appreciate your help.

We know about three languages, A, B and C.
There exists a mapping reduction from A ≤m B, and A ≤m C.

What can be concluded about: A ≤m B union C ?
What can be concluded about: A ≤m B intersection C ?

Answer (score 1):

Not much can be concluded about $A \le_m B \cup C$ since it might not exist.
For example let $A$ and $B$ be two non-trivial languages and define $C = \Sigma^* \setminus B$. Then there is no way to map a word in $\Sigma^* \setminus A$ to a word in $\Sigma^* \setminus (B \cup C)$.

The same choices of $A$, $B$, and $C$ also show that $A \le_m B \cap C$ might not exist. Indeed, there is no way to map a word in $A$ to one in $B \cap C = \emptyset$.